# why im getting this error "401: {"message": "Forbidden - a valid `x-typesense-api-key` header must be sent."}" using typesense's dart lib

Tags: flutter, dart, typesense

When i run the code below i get the error

> 401: {"message": "Forbidden - a valid `x-typesense-api-key` header must be sent."}

i dont understand because I pass in my key

```
final config = Configuration(
      apikey,
      retryInterval: Duration(minutes: 5),
      nodes: {
        Node(Protocol.https, url),
      },

      numRetries: 3, // A total of 4 tries (1 original try + 3 retries)
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    final client = Client(config);
    client.collections.retrieve().then((val) {
      print(val.first);
    });
```

Comment: You are missing header from the api call

Comment: how do I pass the header when using typesense's dart package?

Answer (score 1):

This shows up when I search for *Forbidden - a valid x-typesense-api-key header must be sent*, so here's what was my issue. Make sure you have the correct permissions on the key. Mine was otherwise valid but [restricted](https://typesense.org/docs/0.23.1/api/api-keys.html#generate-scoped-search-key) and I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

Alright I see where the issue is. You are sending the required header which is `apikey` here in your code but you are sending incorrect value of it. You need to make sure you are sending correct apikey from Typesense. Not sure if you have used search key or admin key here but most probably this patch of your code is for searching because you are retrieving so copy and paste the correct search api key like this for example

`final apikey = 'SSw1XmjxjjcA2Raq0UhNPgPff7XTLbF7';`

It should work just fine if the api key is correct.